# How to make Facebook Login persist with Codigniter?

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter, facebook-javascript-sdk

This is my first time integrating Facebook.  I have a site on CI, and so far I'm using mostly the JS SDK.

SO my question is - once a user has logged in with FB, how do you persist his identity and pic from page to page?  Are you making a JS call for the info on to FB.api on every page?  Or do you save info in a session variable via PHP. (Or another way?)

I'm not sure what common practice would be.

Comment: Doesn't the Facebook JS SDK save the data in a cookie?

Answer (score 3):

I use [tank auth](http://konyukhov.com/soft/tank_auth/) to accomplish this.  It is an authentication library for codeigniter that can be used for fb_login too

tere are a couple sample projects on github with tutorials and code.  [this](https://github.com/ericbae/XTA2) looks interesting, as it provides support for many of the popular networks,

you could just start a session and put their facebook data in it.
Each page view you could have a helper that just checks to see if they have any facebook session data set

Comment: Yeah.. but I wanted to do it by hand to get a good feel for things so I could make educated opinions about libraries that I choose in the future.